# how do I configure github if Git is already installed?

Tags: git, github

I have git installed on my mac and I've been learning how to use it on the command line.  I'd now like to start using github.  If I follow the instructions and enter the following commands, will in overwrite my current project?

```
git config --global user.name "YOUR NAME"
git config --global user.email "YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS"
```

Comment: Don't [need to] use `--global` if you are concerned about other [global] settings. See https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Comment: ^ while that's true, surely your name and email *should* be a global setting?

Comment: @scrowler Depends on if you wish it to be. Might want to use different settings for github. If the OP already has 'correct' global settings specified then the above is a no-op. (A example of when they may be different is work vs github settings, eg.)

Answer (score 1):

I stand corrected, `user.name` and `user.email` are parsed by GitHub:

> Your email address will be visible on commits to GitHub. If you'd like
>   to keep your email address private, set your Git config email to
>   username@users.noreply.github.com instead, replacing username with
>   your GitHub username. For more information, see "Keeping your email
>   address private".

(from [here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/))

If your email is already set to your GitHub-linked email address you don't need to make any changes: the global config will be used.  If you instead want to override your global config you can omit the `--global` argument to limit the scope of the configuration change to just the repo you're in when you run the command:

```
git config user.name "YOUR NAME"
git config user.email "YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS"
```